# how to know that whether a network activity in another interface is complete or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some Objective-C classes, with implementation and header files.
One class, which is subclass of `AppDelegate`, has a method which is like below to get data using API calling:

```
@implementation API
    - (NSMutableData *)set:(NSString *) API
    {     
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                 [NSURL URLWithString:GETString]];
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
```

I have some more classes, which is are subclass of `UIViewController`, from where I am calling like below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
API *theInstance = [[API alloc] init];
    [theInstance set:@"&get=different&call=getAPIMethods"];
}
```

Now I want to get the **Response Data** in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` from the `UIViewController` extended class method `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

How can I get the return of the **`NSMutableData`**?

Comment: You have a class that is a subclass of AppDelegate? Why?

Comment: I dont know why. But during adding the class file in the project, I added AppDelegate as the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The object that is the delegate for `NSURLConnection` will need to adopt the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol. The delegate object will need to implement the protocol method `connection:didReceiveData:` in order to save the received data.  When the connection is completed, `connectionDidFinishLoading:` will be called.  At this point you will need to communicate to the `UIViewController` the data. The easiest way to do this would be to send out a `NSNotification`.